# Does Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table automatically choose the lowest latency route to the cosmos DB if replicated globally?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to set up a cosmos DB infrastructure for my game. I have been looking into using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table library but i am unsure if the cosmos db is replicated in multiple locations, that the call to this library will choose the lowest latency route without any further azure configuration.

Hope this is enough info to answer the question.

Regards,
Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB is smart enough to work out which is the nearest datacenter in which you have replicated data in, in order to provide the best possible latency.

However, you can also specify the preferred locations yourself by setting the `Preferred Locations` setting of the `CreateCloudTableClient` by providing a comma-separated list of preferred (multi-homing) locations for reads.

Read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet#azure-cosmos-db-capabilities).

Comment: Cheers Nick, that is really helpful.